# Android Platform tools installed but still getting -bash: adb: command not found

Tags: android, react-native, adb

Adb shows a successful install with an installation path. However, when I run adb it says command not found. However, I am running this not from within the platform-tools directory. 
I'm on Mac OS High Sierra. 
How can I use adb from any directory?

Comment: please share what you tried like the path and command

Comment: Did you install with homebrew?